# NextJS13 + Auth0 - Redirect user based on certain conditions

Tags: redirect, next.js, auth0, next.js13

I am building a new application using NextJS13 + Auth0.  NextJs version is `13.4.19` whereas auth0 lib version is `3.1.0`. I am using Server components. The file is `\app\api\auth\[auth0]\route.ts`

I have a custom callback handler

```
const afterCallback = async (req: NextRequest, session: Session, state: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    if (session.user.email_verified) {
        console.log('email verified..continuing')
        return session;
    } else {
      // redirect('http://localhost:3000/verify-email', RedirectType.replace);     
      // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('http://localhost:3000/verify-email'))
       headers.set('location', '/verify-email');
    }

    console.log('printing after redirect')    
    return session;
};
```

My authHandlers

```
export const GET = handleAuth({
    callback: async (req: any, res: any) => {
        try {
            console.log('callback method called')
           return await handleCallback(req, res, {
                afterCallback,
               // redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard'
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    },

  login: async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        console.log('login method called')
        return await handleLogin(req, res, {
            // authorizationParams: {
            //     redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback',
            //   },
            returnTo: `/dashboard`,
        });
    },
```

I am not sure how to redirect the user to the `/verify-email` page when the user's email is not verified.

I tried different options but no luck. Using `redirect` throws an error as per docs.- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect
There is another example in the docs using `headers.set('location', '/verify-email');`
However that doesn't work either as headers are read-only. I get the below error
`CAUSE: next_headers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.headers.set is not a function`

Does anyone know how I can push the user to `/verify-email` page in case the email is unverified. TIA

Answer (score 0):

see docs here: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/26b54f3/src/handlers/callback.ts#L74C4-L74C4

````
 * @example Redirect successful login based on claim
 *
 * ```js
 * // pages/api/auth/[auth0].js
 * import { handleAuth, handleCallback } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
 *
 * const afterCallback = (req, res, session, state) => {
 *   if (!session.user.isAdmin) {
 *     res.setHeader('Location', '/admin');
 *   }
 *   return session;
 * };
 *
 * export default handleAuth({
 *   async callback(req, res) {
 *     try {
 *       await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback });
 *     } catch (error) {
 *       res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
 *     }
 *   }
 * });
 * ```
````